# best practices to execute the almost the same command several times

Tags: bash

I need help figuring out the best practices to execute those commands in bash.
It's a command that sends a text, and I need to repeat this command for several phone numbers and for several dates... about 250 times in total. The command returns something like this `{"creditsUsed":1.00,"snapshotId":107416458}` if it went well. An error code otherwise.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Primotexto-ApiKey: 784155c6a3c9ceed9d0a4d1ffdb67466" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"number":"+317877592979" , "message":"test\nother line" , "sender":"myCompany" , "date": 1539272220000}' \
https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send;

curl -X POST \
-H "X-Primotexto-ApiKey: 784155c6a3c9ceed9d0a4d1ffdb67466" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"number":"+317877574678" , "message":"test2\nother line" , "sender":"myCompany" , "date": 1539272220001}' \
https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send;

curl -X POST \
-H "X-Primotexto-ApiKey: 784155c6a3c9ceed9d0a4d1ffdb67466" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"number":"+317877574676" , "message":"test3\nother line" , "sender":"myCompany" , "date": 1539272220002}' \
https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send;

...
```

Should I end it with `;` or `&&` ?
Should I write a script ?
Can I do something better with json ?

**EDIT** maybe I could build a json file like this :

```
{
    "number":"+336770002979",
    "message":"La plupart\ntest",
    "sender":"BEinstitute",
    "date": 1539286620000
},
{
    "number":"+336600000780",
    "message":"La plupart\ntest",
    "sender":"BEinstitute",
    "date": 1539286620000
}
```

and the run through each object with curl. Any idea how to do this ?

```
$ curl -X POST -H "X-Primotexto-H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @json.json https://api.primotexto.com/v2/notification/messages/send;
```

only reads the first object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all depends on your requirements. But writing a script is rarely a bad idea, especially for repetitive tasks.

But between `;` and `&&`, it is a completely different result.

- `;` is a command separator
- `&&` is a conditional operator (so is `||`)

For example:

If you try the following command:

```
touch /var/no-permission; echo "It works!"
```

The first part of the line (before the semicolumn) will fail since you won't have access to create files in `/var` (as long as you aren't logged in as `root` of course). But you will see the line "`t works!` printed in your console because the semicolumn is just a separator and doesn't care if the previous command works or not.

However, if you try the following command:

```
touch /var/no-permission && echo "It works!"
```

This won't do anything so you won't see `It works!` in your console. Since the first command will fail, the `&&` operator will not try to run the next command. (You can also use `||` instead of `&&` to do its opposite. So the second command only runs when the first fails)

So if one of the commands fails, all the others should stop, then use `&&`. If they should continue, use `;`.

Not: If you can write each command on a new line, it's as if you separate them by a semicolumn. For example,

```
touch /var/no-permission; echo "It works!"
```

Is the same as

```
touch /var/no-permission
echo "It works!"
```

Comment: thank you, I understand for the $$ and ; question. Can you help me write the script , is that possible  to put the content of all the `-d {}` in a json file ?

Comment: @Louis we can help you make something, but we won't do it for you. Go ahead and ask about `-d {}` in a new question. You'll probably have more luck on [so] about that, but _only ask about specific issues_.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767726/batch-curl-d-from-json-file  :)

Comment: @Louis Before you post new questions, don't forget to upvote and accept the existing answers if they helped you...  **;-)**

Comment: @TheWander It'd be perfectly fine here as well. It's not specifically a programming question, just a scripting one